# How to apply additional operations to groupby groups in Pandas?

Tags: python

In sports betting arbitrage in a three-way outcome match `if ( (1/decimal odds 1) + (1/decimal odds 2) + (1/decimal draw odds) ) < 1` there is a profit opportunity.  Where each of these odds are from a different sportsbook on the same game.  I have a dataframe of 1000s of games from different sportsbooks.  Some games are the same game while others are not.

Here is an example of 3 rows:
[image]

Basically, I can group these games together using something like `df.groupby(["game", "league", "date"])`

How could I use these groups of games to determine where there are arbitrage opportunities?  I was thinking sorting each group to the largest decimal odds and testing if it is profitable.  If it is not then the entire game group can be dropped.  Although I am not totally sure how to do this.

I was comparing looping the lists against itself through 3 nested loops but this was super slow and this operation is very time-sensitive.  Any ideas on the most efficient way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(["game", "league", "date"]).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
grouped_df2 = grouped_df.groupby(["game", "league", "date"]).filter(lambda x: (1 / max(x.odds1d)) + (1 / max(x.odds2d)) + (1 / max(x.draw_oddsd)) < 1)
```

This greatly reduces the size of the dataframe (less than 1% of original data frame) to only profitable games.  From here I can do whatever manipulation I want without too much worry about processing time.